# Extraer lineas de un .txt que empiezen con cierta palabra usando regex, y luego escriba las lineas extraidas en otro .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, regex, filereader

Necesito poner una regex que agarre al usuario que ingreso el texto(input_text), luego que busque en el log las frases (lineas que empiezen con ese username: ) corte y se quede con las lineas listas para escribir en otro txt, respetando los \n correspondientes, osea que no se unan todas las lineas.

Con este input:

```
ElectrikVocal95#9525: de que hablamos
```

Debe guardar en una variable `"ElectrikVocal95#9525"`

El programa deberia buscar en un archivo log.txt aquellas lineas que comienzen con el usuario que guardo en esa variable, que lo tuvo que extraer del input_text

```
ElectrikVocal95#9525: los trenes son geniales
Me gustan creo que son interesantes
ElectrikVocal95#9525: recuerdad lo que dije
Tu me dijiste 'los trenes son geniales'
ElectrikVocal95#9525: recuerda que los aviones son rapidicimos
Interesante, lo recordare
ElectrikVocal95#9525: que te pedi que recuerdes?
Creo que me dijiste que los aviones son rapidicimos
ElectrikVocal95#9525: que te pedi que recuerdes?
Me dijiste que los aviones son rapidicimos
```

Y debe escribir en otro .txt las lineas de las que quito el user_name (depende de lo que extrajo del input), quedando solo aquellas que empezaban con el user_name y se les recorto:

```
los trenes son geniales
recuerdad lo que dije
recuerda que los aviones son rapidicimos
que te pedi que recuerdes?
que te pedi que recuerdes?
```

No pongo el code porque es bastante extenso y no esta funcionando bien.
La verdad me estoy liando bastante con este code, espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenemos nuestro archivo de log al cual llamare log.txt:

```c
ElectrikVocal95#9525: los trenes son geniales
Me gustan creo que son interesantes
ElectrikVocal95#9525: recuerdad lo que dije
Tu me dijiste 'los trenes son geniales'
ElectrikVocal95#9525: recuerda que los aviones son rapidicimos
Interesante, lo recordare
ElectrikVocal95#9525: que te pedi que recuerdes?
Creo que me dijiste que los aviones son rapidicimos
ElectrikVocal95#9525: que te pedi que recuerdes?
Me dijiste que los aviones son rapidicimos
```

Eh creado dos funciones una para obtener los mensajes y la otra para escribirlos en el nuevo archivo:

```py
NombreDeUsuario="ElectrikVocal95#9525"

# Esta funcion retorna los mensajes como una lista 
def obtenerUnicamenteMensajes():
    import re
    """ Nuestra regex consite en 2 grupos, el primer grupo no es capturado
        y hace referencia a 'ElectrikVocal95#9525: ', y el segundo grupo
        hace referencia al mensaje y como es el unico grupo capturado estamos
        hablando del grupo uno."""
    regex=f'^(?:{NombreDeUsuario}:\s)(.*)$'
    regexCompilada=re.compile(rf'{regex}')

    mensajes=[]

    # Abrimos el archivo de log y lo recorremos linea a linea para filtrar los mensajes
    archivoDeLog=open("log.txt", "r")
    for linea in archivoDeLog:
        mensajeCompleto=regexCompilada.match(linea)
        if mensajeCompleto:
            # Añadimos un salto de linea al final del mensaje
            mensajes+=[f'{mensajeCompleto.group(1)}\n']

    archivoDeLog.close()
    return mensajes

def escribirMensajesEnNuevoArchivo():
    # Damos un nombre al archivo en el que escribiremos los mensajes
    nombreDeNuevoArchivo=f'{NombreDeUsuario}_Mensajes.txt'
    
    nuevoArchivo=open(nombreDeNuevoArchivo , "w")
    nuevoArchivo.writelines(obtenerUnicamenteMensajes())
    nuevoArchivo.close()

escribirMensajesEnNuevoArchivo()
```

Como resultado tenemos al archivo ElectrikVocal95#9525_Mensajes.txt:

```c
los trenes son geniales
recuerdad lo que dije
recuerda que los aviones son rapidicimos
que te pedi que recuerdes?
que te pedi que recuerdes?
```

Eso es todo, espero te funcione.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: @ElectrisikVocal ¿te funciono?

Comment: Me funciono, lo unico que quedaria es la primera parte en donde en lugar de ya tener a `ElectrikVocal95#9525` en la variable sino que tenga que extraerlo de un input_text donde ese user ponga algo como: "ElectrikVocal95#9525: de que habiamos hablado?" , entonces que separe esa oracion en 2, quedando en una variable "ElectrikVocal95#9525"  y en la otra "de que habiamos hablado?", y luego ahi aplicar lo de tu code